# What semantical is there in attribute grammars?

Tags: terminology, compilers, semantics, attribute-grammars

I've been reading about attribute grammars since I'm trying to extend CFGs to semantics.

What I'm finding difficult to grasp is the use of the word "semantics" in the context of attribute grammars.

For example [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Eengelen/courses/COP402003/notes4.html):
[image]

One can see the term *semantic rule*. But isn't this just arithmetic?
What semantical is here?

Can you give a clearer sense of how attribute grammars can describe semantics?
 Or what semantics means in the context of attribute grammars?

Comment: Attribute grammars describe semantic by giving rules on how attributes of members in a production are computed from the attributes of the other members.

Comment: @AProgrammer Semantic means meaning. But what's the meaning here? To me it seems that the semantic rule is "just another way" of saying the same thing that's in the production. And also in such way that's easily implemented in a programming language.

Comment: The '+' on the production side is a character with no meaning attached (grammars are a way to describe strings), the '+' on the semantic rule side is part of the mathematical notation which has a meaning.  If you were describing concatenation, the production for Ada would use '&', the production for Perl would use '.' but the semantic rule would the be same for both language as long as you are using the same formalism form them (semantic grammars are not a formalism for describing semantic, they are a way to link such formalism with grammar productions).

Comment: @AProgrammer Ok so the semantic rule tells "what do to in this production rule". It's like an interpretation of "mere symbols".

Comment: More or less yes: attributes may flow in both directions.  i.e. you could have an attribute for E2 which is computed from an attribute from E1 (say the type in a language which is using context for overload resolution), and a semantic rule could contains attributes of both kind.

Comment: I'm still wondering though, can attribute grammars be used to describe natural language semantics? How (since natural language semantics is not necessarily about arithmetic?)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33279/discussion-between-aprogrammer-and-mavavilj).